# Curves with interchanged curvature and torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Imagine you have two curves $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, such that the curvature $\kappa_1$ of $\alpha_1$ is the torsion $\tau_2$ of $\alpha_2$ and the torsion $\tau_1$ of $\alpha_1$ is the curvature $\kappa_2$ of $\alpha_2$. Is there any relationship between the curves $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?

Comment: What have you tried? I presume the statement is that both curves are arclength parametrized and the curvatures and torsions are compared at the points corresponding by this parametrization.

Comment: Exactly. $\alpha_1,\alpha_2:I\subset\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}^3$ are two arclength parametrized curves with $\kappa_1(s)=\tau_2(s)$ and $\tau_1(s)=\kappa_2(s)$.

Comment: OK, so tell us what you have tried. Also, where did this question come from?

Comment: The question is motivated by the following. Let $\alpha$ be an arclength parametrized curve with Frenet frame $\{T,N,B\}$. Suppose, for example, that curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$ are positive. By using the Frenet equations 
$$T'=\kappa N, N'=-\kappa T-\tau B, B'=\tau N,$$
we obtain that the curve $\beta$ defined by $$\beta(s)=\int_{s_0}^sB(u)du$$ is an arclength parametrized curve whose Frenet frame $\{T_\beta,N_\beta,B_\beta\}$ is given by $$T_\beta=B,\quad N_\beta=N,\quad B_\beta=-T .$$
Moreover, its curvature and torsion are
$$\kappa_\beta=\tau,\quad  \tau_\beta=-\kappa.$$

Comment: Right. I know no further answer.